# How can i slideUp a .HTML on my page with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a image with a ID.
IF someone click on that image a .HTML must slide up or fade in on the same page.
The .HTML page have also a close button so they can close the HTML page

But how can i show the .HTML page with jQuery or Javascript?

I want something like this :
http://elitemodel.fr/fr/mainboard/women

If you click on a photo, (a .html page will slide up with the information)
I a have everything done, except the code for showing the .HTML page

I have tried this but no results :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ams2t').click(function(){   
        $('#body').load('pictures/amsterdam1.html');
     });
});
```

ams2t is the id of the image : `<img id="ams1t" class="thumb" src="images/amsterdam/thumb/ams1.jpg" alt="" />`

So if some click on that picture..
picuture/amsterdam1.html must slide UP or Fade in

Something like this :

```
$("#ams1t").click(function () {
   $('#ams1').slideDown( "slow", function() {
     });
});
```

Comment: Ensure that when it loads, the parent is hidden, then when you show the data use the callbacks which are available or if none are available you could use a promise to slide down.

Comment: How, do you have a example?

Comment: Do you mean to use [`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) instead?

Answer (score 0):

- You didn't specify if `#ams1t` is loaded statically or dynamically, so I've attached the click handler to the document to be safe.
- Add `<div id='#amsterdam1_container' style='display:none;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;z-index:999'>\\content</div>` around the content within `amsterdam1.html`.  This will be used for the `fadeIn()` once the file has been loaded.

  ```
  $(document).off("click","#ams1t").on("click","#ams1t", function(){
     $.get( "pictures/amsterdam1.html", function( data ) {
       $( "body" ).append( data );
       //fade in 
       $('#amsterdam1_container').fadeIn();
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: How can i slide down the data?

Comment: `.slideDown()` instead of `.fadeIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, slideUp actually hides html data from page and slideDown shows that data. So you have to use slideDown instead of slideUp.

You need to pass the ID by jquery ajax or post method to another page. That page will fetch the related data associated with that ID from database and return the data to the first page. The first page will then show this data to any predefined div.

So lets do it first by adding a div to the first page.

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

An image `id` is unique. Your page may contain hundred of pictures. If you add click event based on `id` you have to add code for each id. So instead adding click event on `id`, add it on `class` instead. So add or modify this code to your first page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#result").hide();
    $('.thumb').click(function(){
         var imageId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');   
         $.post("anotherpage.php", {id: imageId}, function(data){
           $("#result").html(data).slideDown("slow");
         });
     });
});
```

and in anotherpage.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']){
 $query = "SELECT details FROM table WHERE id='$_POST['id']";
 // Execute this query and fetch the result
 .....................
 .....................
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc()){
  echo $row['details'];
}
```

I mentioned processing code of anotherpage.php in a very simpler code. You have to verify the ID before processing if you want to prevent sql injection. You might have your own mysql or mysqli processing code. I just demonstrated the process here.

If you don't want to use php and want that all details will be loaded with picture then you have to load all the details of those pictures in separate divs. Like for image id `p01` you have to load details in a div on pageload.

```
<img id="p01" class="thumb" src="images/amsterdam/thumb/ams1.jpg" alt="" />
<div id="d_p01" class="picDetails">Picture details of p01</div>
```

Then add this jquery code instead first one:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#result").hide();
      $(".picDetails").hide();
        $('.thumb').click(function(){
             var imageId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
             var divId = 'd_'+imageId;   
               $("#"+divId).slideDown("slow");             
         });
    });
```

Or if you want to load the related pic details from another html page then it is also possible. For this, my advice is to include all the picture details in anotherpage.html in separate paragraphs with ids like this:

```
<p id="d_p01">This is details of first picture</p>
<p id="d_p02">This is details of second picture</p>
```

Then add this code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#result").hide();
        $('.thumb').click(function(){
             var imageId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
             var pId = '#d_'+imageId;   
               $("#result").load("anotherpage.html pId").slideDown("slow");             
         });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't want to use .PHP

Comment: Then how you will get the details of the image? If you have 50 pictures in a webpage and you want, the details will be loaded with those pictures in pure html then the intial page load time may be huge.  Anyway I have added extra code if you don't want to use php for processing. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, can i speak with you on chat?

Comment: I am not very regular in stackoverflow. If the time of you and me matches, ob course we can chat.